# Lodash : _Filter, but returns an array of objects with specific keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

Im making a function which compares two arrays of objects and returns two subset arrays of objects. The first returned array being a set of objects which were not included within the array passed within the second prop, and the second returned array being a set of objects which were not included within the first array but are now included within the second.

This works, however, i want to add an extra functionality to return the second array with specific keys. Is there anyway to utilise lodash "pickBy" functionality within the filter function, or will i have to create an extra recursive section?

```
function extract_removed_new (before, after, matching, pickBy = [])  {

let before_ = cloneDeep(before)
let new_ = _.filter(after, (item) => {
    let index_ = _.findIndex(before_, function (i) {
        return _.get(i, matching) == _.get(item, matching)
    })
    if(index_ !== -1) {
        before_.splice(index_, 1)
        return false
    }
    if(pickBy.length > 0) {
        return _.pickBy(item, function(value, key) {
            if(key in pickBy) {
                return true
            }
        });
    }
    return true
})
return [before_, new_]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash compact, with `map` I was able to get exactly what I needed.

```
function extract_removed_new (before, after, matching, pickBy = [])  {

let before_ = cloneDeep(before)
let new_ = _.compact(_.map(after, (item) => {
    let index_ = _.findIndex(before_, function (i) {
        return _.get(i, matching) == _.get(item, matching)
    })
    if(index_ !== -1) {
        before_.splice(index_, 1)
        return false
    }
    if(pickBy.length > 0) {
        return _.pickBy(item, function(value, key) {
            if(pickBy.includes(key)) {
                return true
            }
        });
    }
    return item
}))
return [before_, new_]
```

}